# How to use the "Project Drawer" in TextMate 2 when it doesn't seem to exist?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

On TextMate 2 and opening two files in two different locations such as `/path/1/file.txt` and `/path/2/file.txt`, I am no longer seeing a way to perform diffs as before since one cannot select files in the project "drawer."  We now have a file browser that seems to have taken its place and thus no way to pick the two opposing files.  This also precludes any other command that requires multi file selection that are not within the file structure.

Am I missing something that would allow this to work properly when dealing with files in two different paths?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a new trick. It's one we learned when grep in project would go insane when you had a project with files whose common ancestor was root or some directory far above the files.  Instead of opening your files like:

```
mate /foo/bar/baz /quix/quacks/quux
```

You do the following, assuming you're in an empty directory or don't care that its files will be included in the project as well

```
ln /foo/bar/baz /quix/quacks/quux . && mate .
```

That can obviously be wrapped up into a function to reduce the syntactical difference. In fact, at one point, I actually wrote a wrapper script around mate to do that transparently when needed AND clean up the hard linked files after I closed the project or quit TextMate. That went away with some bad hard drive though.

Anyhow I HTH